# What happened to Captain Jack in Turn Left?

Tags: doctor-who, torchwood

In *Turn Left*, Donna is taken back to the moment she turned left at a road pushing her onto a path that caused her to meet the Doctor. Instead of turning left she goes right, creating a universe where the Doctor dies fighting the Racnoss because Donna doesn't stop him. We discover that in this universe, many of the disasters the Doctor stopped are still stopped or mitigated by others like Sarah Jane or Torchwood, but many disasters still happen.

At one point we discover that most of Torchwood was killed stopping the Sontarans and Jack was kidnapped by them. What do the Sontarans do with Jack? They obviously can't kill him so do they keep him locked up or study him to find out how he survives or do they do something else?

Comment: The details were not disclosed, but we can be sure, that in just a few generations Sontarans will look less like potatoes and more like John Barrowman.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### We don't know.

Since this version of reality only appeared in the single episode *Turn Left*, we have basically no knowledge about it other than what's stated explicitly in that episode. All we know about Captain Jack Harkness in the "turn right" version of the universe is the following:

> ROSE: It's the ATMOS devices. We're lucky, it's not so bad here. Britain hasn't got that much petrol. But all over Europe, China, South Africa, they're getting choked by gas.
> DONNA: Can't anyone stop it?
> ROSE: Yeah, they're trying right now, this little band of fighters, on board the Sontaran ship. Any second now.
> (The sky burns.)
> DONNA: And that was?
> ROSE: That was the Torchwood team. Gwen Cooper, Ianto Jones, they gave their lives. And **Captain Jack Harkness has transported to the Sontaran home world.** There's no one left.
>
> <sub>-- Series 4 Episode 11, *Turn Left* (emphasis mine)</sub>

Note that it doesn't say he was *kidnapped* by the Sontarans, nor that he "was transported" to Sontar (which would suggest against his will), but that he "has transported".

- Perhaps he went to Sontar with a honking great gun, using the teleporters that we saw on the Sontarans' spaceship in *The Sontaran Stratagem* and *The Poison Sky*, and committed himself to destroying them or at least ensuring they wouldn't be able to come and attack Earth again. A massive great punch-up between Jack Harkness and millions of Sontarans would be a sight to see, and I'm sure both sides would have a great deal of fun.
- Perhaps the Sontarans did kidnap him so that they could try to turn him into a weapon they could use in their fifty-thousand-year-long war against the Rutans. An immortal warrior would be a great asset for them if they succeeded in recruiting him.

Comment: Didn't Jack still have his teleporter wrist-band device thingy at the time?  He might not have needed to use the Sontarans' teleporters if he had his own.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Oh, excuse me. That is not teleportation! It's like "I've got a sports car and you've got a space hopper." (and you must think all I do in comments is make subtle references, after The Prisoner and now this)

Comment: And out of universe clearly we were meant to read this as "Jack's gone for good, just like all the rest", except they couldn't kill him off so they made up something else to get him out of the way.

Comment: Actually I thought he transported to their planet to destroy it or something. In that case he could very well be floating in space

Comment: Is "Captain Jack Harkness **has** transported to the Sontaran home world" the wording in an official script? I have watched that scene many times, and it always sounded like **was** rather than **has** to me. I'm not doubting you, just interested in the source.

Comment: @Blackwood Not official, only the Chakoteya scripts (fan-made, but usually very reliable). I just re-watched [that scene](https://youtu.be/JdhRdF08fGY?t=55) and it sounds like "has" to me, but YMMV :-)